# Is there any solution for this annoying error?

Tags: spring, netbeans, glassfish-3

I am using NetBeans 7.0 and Glassfish 3.1 with Spring, version 3.0.2 and often I receive errors like this one:

**"someProjectName\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1060: Unable to delete file SomeProjectname\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.6.jar"**

Anyone have any ideas what could be the cause for this?

Comment: If you are using your project's Clean or Clean and Build menu item, you may be able to make progress by avoiding these items...  By using the Run item and leveraging 'Deploy on Save' you should not need to use the 'clean targets' very often...

Comment: can you please explain... what actually  happens when I select "Clean and Build" ? I am not aware of all those background stuffs.... thanks for the suggestion though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a not a bug, It may happen due to a number of reasons:

1. the jar is still executing.(in memory)
2. Some page is open which is using the jar.
3. The explorer window containing the folder which contains the jar is open.

There may be other reasons too...but I solved the problem on more than one occasions by eliminating the above three conditions.

See if it works for u.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what of knurdy's suggested... You might find [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) a helpful tool in such problem. Only if you are working on Microsoft Windows platform, which I guess you do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close the NetBeans
2. Stop the AppServer (I use GlassFish)
3. Start NetBeans
4. Clean and Deploy
5. Start AppServer

It works.

Comment: Objective of the question was to know the cause of the problem. Why we need to restart netbeans ? Any thing other than restarting the netbeans would have been accepted as an answer..

Comment: Sorry. I just wanted to give a practical solution. But if you need an explain about this problem here is a hypothesis: the .jar has been locked. There can be many causes of this kind of locking. For instance a deadlock or so. Istvan

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the file is loaded on the server and hence been currently used. You just have to `stop the server` **>** `clean or clean and build your project` and it will be removed. No need to close Netbeans or kill java.exe.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows. Go to task manager-->Processes and Kill java.exe process there. it will solve the problem if that jar is still running in memory.